# Google AppScript sending GET requests with bodies, never POST requests?

Tags: javascript, nginx, flask, google-apps-script

I've been scratching my head at this for a few days. Here's my AppScript code:

```
data = {'api_dev_key':'meow',
        'api_option':'paste',
        'api_paste_code':'dog',
        'api_paste_format':'python'}


var options =
      {
        "method" : "post",
        "payload": data
      };


var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(testing_flask_url, options);
Logger.log(response);
```

No matter what, this data gets sent as the *body to a GET request* to my Flask endpoint.

Weirdly, my nginx logs always show *two* requests simulatenously: one POST, and one GET:

```
[17/Mar/2020:15:29:22 +0000] "POST /myendpoint HTTP/1.1" 308 267 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: <id>)"
[17/Mar/2020:15:29:22 +0000] "GET /myendpooint
```

What are these two requests?

How can I get AppScript to send an actual POST request?

Comment: Is the data JSON?? I mean does it needs to be sent as JSON?

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth It doesn't need to be. I'm fine with anything. It just needs to be in the body.

Comment: What is the response coming try this  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

Comment: That's not a function. This has nothing to do with the response.

Comment: Did you try `Logger.log(response.getContentText());` and / or `"muteHttpExceptions": true`?

Comment: @ziganotschka I get that `getContextText()` is not a function. I have not tried `muteHttpExceptions`.

Comment: Replace your url through the test url provided in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)): `'https://httpbin.org/post'` and add the lines `Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());   Logger.log(response.getContentText());` If this works as intended, it means that there is a problem with your url or your post request is not formatted in a way your endpoint expects. Depending on the endpoint you need to provide e.g. headers.

Comment: It's just a regular Flask endpoint. It should work out of the box with any basic POST.

Comment: The payload type in a `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` call defaults to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.  Unless the content type is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', then you should specify a `contentType` in the options.  You should use `contentType:"application/json"` in your options when sending a payload that is JSON, which is what you are using.  I don't know if that's the problem, but it's "good practice" and has solved issues for other people.

Comment: @AlanWells I've tried that as well. Again, it seems to be a GET request being sent in the first place.

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but have you tried reverting back to `"runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5"` to test if that makes any difference?  From code editor, "run" menu, disable V8.  Or set `"runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5"` in the appsscript.json file.

Comment: Did you try what @ziganotschka said? Or try making a POST request using an API tester like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/talend-api-tester-free-ed/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm. In my experience its either an auth issue or malformed request. Once its working from an API tester, then duplicate the request in GAS.

Comment: The post request probably fails and gets  redirected to a get. Stringify the payload: `"payload": JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Reverting to deprecated_es5 like Alan said did not work.

Comment: @TheMaster Would an application really do that? Either way, stringifying the data had no impact.

Comment: Try the API teeter. In every case I’ve come across it’s an issue with how the API is being called. Get the call to work outside of GAS, then replicate the call, including headers, in GAS. It may be something behind the scene like implied basic authentication.

Comment: Could you try the same request with ``curl`` and see if it works as expected??

Comment: @TheMaster it works with a python client, just a simple request

Comment: Not enough. It needs to work with curl